# Sublime Text 2 OS specific Run configuration?

Tags: build-process, sublimetext2

I would like to create 4 build options for building Actionscript files. One for Building and one for Running in Linux, and the same for Windows.

**Is it possible to do this?**

Currently it seems 'windows' and 'linux' sections can only overwrite the default build option?

My current broken .sublime-build file is:

```
{
    "selector": "source.actionscript",

    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": [
            "${packages}\\User\\Flash-build.bat",
            "${project_path}",
            "${file}"
        ],

        "variants":
        [
            {
                "name": "Run",
                "cmd": [
                    "${packages}\\User\\Flash-run.bat",
                    "${file_path}",
                    "${file_base_name}"
                ]
            }
        ],
    },

    "linux":
    {
        "cmd": [
            "${packages}/User/Flash-build.sh",
            "${packages}",
            "${project_path}",
            "${file_path}",
            "${file_base_name}"
        ],

        "variants":
        [
            {
                "name": "Run",
                "cmd": [
                    "${packages}/User/Flash-run.sh",
                    "${packages}",
                    "${project_path}",
                    "${file_path}",
                    "${file_base_name}"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I can't see why your solution wouldn't work, however, I know that the following works for me.

Sublime preference files can be specified on a per-OS basis.  You could create three separate files:

- User/actionscript (OSX).sublime-build
- User/actionscript (Linux).sublime-build
- User/actionscript (Windows).sublime-build

Sublime will only pick up the one that is relevant to your OS.